# Spacing between element like tab functionality

Tags: html, cpu-word

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I can manage the second words to be exactly at the same distance from the start of the line by pressing the `Tab` key.

I want to have the same functionality in HTML. I know I can do this using `<table>` but I'm curious to know if there is any easier way like MS word or not.

```html
<span>Firstword<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Second<span>
<br>
<span>Second<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Third<span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flex css to achieve the desired result. Also, add a margin-right according to your need.

```html
<style>
 .row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 }

 .col {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-right: 1em;
 }
</style>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <span>Firstword</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Second</span>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="col">
    <span>Third</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Fourth</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the width of the spans, so the others will be in the same position:

```css
.tab{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<span class="tab">Firstword</span><span>Second</span>
<br>
<span class="tab">Second</span><span>Third</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution using [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

It is very complex, but gives you (like Word) total control over spacing on the page or element.

I divided the grid in columns of 10 pixels and rows of 20 pixels.

```css
body {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 20px);
}

span:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column: 1
}

span:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: 12
}
```

```html
<span>Firstword</span><span>Second</span>
<span>Second</span><span>Third</span>
```